# Disable Automatic Capitalization in Windows

Tags: windows

When im changing picture name windows auto change the first letter to be uppercase and its make me problem with the names and my hosting server. How i change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's coming from Windows Autocorrection. I don't know which Windows you're using. Here's a tutorial for disabling autocorrection in Win8:
http://www.convergencenetworks.com/disable-windows-8-autocorrect/